# How I test this code in DevCpp? (has other 2 .h)

Tags: c++, dev-c++

How I teste this code in DevCpp: because show no main error
undefined reference to `WinMain'

```
#include "Expression.h"

using namespace std;

 expression encontra seu valor

void Expression::infixToPostfix()
{ 
    string teste=getInfix();
    int n = teste.length();

    char atual[n+1];
    char x;

    strcpy(atual, teste.c_str());


    Stack<char> operadores; 
    Stack<char> pos_fixa; 

    for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++){
        if(isdigit(atual[i])){
            pos_fixa.push(atual[i]);
        }
        else{
            if(atual[i] != ')'){
                operadores.push(atual[i]);
            }
            else{
                while(!operadores.empty() || x != '('){
                    operadores.getTop(x);
                    if(x!='('){
                        pos_fixa.push(x);
                    }
                    operadores.pop(x);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while(!pos_fixa.empty()){
        pos_fixa.getTop(x);
        printf("%c\n",x);
        postfix=postfix+x;
        pos_fixa.pop(x);
    }
}
```

and I don't know how I run this exemple program to test
because don't have a way to create a main? or anithing like that? has other parts but stackoverflow don't allowed to declare

Comment: First you need to make sure you're making a console program and not a Windows program. It is looking for WinMain because that is the entry point for a Windows GUI program. I don't use DevCpp so I don't know what to tell you to do other than read through the documentation. That said, you will need to make a main function in one of your cpp files.

Comment: Technically that's not valid C++ code. C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (like your array `actual` is), it's a non-portable extension of the language that a limited set of compilers have. You should use a `std::vector` instead. Or since you just use it as a null-terminated string, why not simply use the `std::string` object `teste` directly?

Comment: Other problem include the loop condition `i<n+1` which should be `i < n` (since you don't want to use the terminator itself), or better yet would have been a [ranged for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). And you using the variable `x` before it's initialized.

Comment: `i<n+1` is because `char atual[n+1];` but the central problem is the windows and DevCpp, I need to use other OS or compilator

Comment: It's true that a string of `n` characters need an array of `n + 1` elements to fit the null-terminator. But using `n + 1` in a loop condition will *include* the null-terminator inside the loop. That's seldom wanted.

Comment: really I created a main was easier